# Convert Image File to a Negative

Tags: kotlin

I want to get the negative of a specific Image based on following command-line input.

```
-in xyz.png -out xyz_negative.png
```

The files loaded are stored in a specific folder.

Here is what I was/am trying to do so far.

1. Read a png file
2. Calculate RGB values for each pixel
3. Calculate Negative RGB Values
4. Set new RGB Values for png file to get the negative

I am kinda stuck on the last step since the new .png ist not the negative. Here is my code, if anybody could help me or point me in the right direction I would be much obliged.

```
import java.awt.Color
import java.io.File
import javax.imageio.ImageIO

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    if (args.isNotEmpty()) {
        val myFile = File(
                "/Users/xyz/IdeaProjects/Seam Carving/Seam Carving/task/${args[1]}")
        val importedImage = ImageIO.read(myFile)
        for (x in 0 until importedImage.width) {
            for (y in 0 until importedImage.height) {
                val pixel = importedImage.getRGB(x, y)
                var color = Color(pixel, true)
                val redNegative = 255 - color.red
                val greenNegative = 255 - color.green
                val blueNegative = 255 - color.blue
                color = Color(redNegative, blueNegative, greenNegative)
                importedImage.setRGB(x, y, color.rgb)
            }
        }
        ImageIO.write(importedImage, "png", File("/Users/xyz/IdeaProjects/Seam Carving/Seam Carving/task/${args[3]}"))
    }
}
```

[What its supposed to look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrZLs.png)

[What my image looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztmNi.png)

Comment: “the new .png is not the negative” — are you sure?  I've just tried that code, and it successfully created a negative of a png.  Are you looking at a cached version or something?

Comment: @gidds I am doing this for a course on Jetbrains Academy. I thought there has to be some kind of mistake in my code or a step I am missing because when testing I am getting the error messages `Hash sum of your image (6ca3d2d38eef3b90ab3ac867388208c2) does not match expected value` and the Images I create do not look anything like a negative, so I came to the conclusion that I either made a mistake or missing an important step

Comment: @gidds Thank you very much for helping me. I don't know how to upvote you but I will. Stupid me switched the green and blue RGB. Here was the mistake

Comment: Ah yes, that would explain it — and we should both have spotted that mistake!  At least you know the reason, and it was an easy fix.  (Don't worry about upvoting a comment.  That didn't justify a full answer.)